# How to emulate an electric signal (Enigma emulator)

Tags: c#, encryption, emulation

I want to emulate Enigma machine, therefore I need to emulate an electric signal.

[image: How enigma works: plugboard and scramblers]

If you're not familiar with Enigma, here's how it works: the electric signal travels from plugboard through scrabmlers. Scrabmlers rotate, so the path of the signal changes (output is different).

So far, I've been doing it like this (this is a simplified code):

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < key.Length; j++)
    {
        // encrypting
        data[i] = scramblers[j][(byte)(data[i] + key[j])];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < key.Length; j++)
    {
        // rotating scramblers
        key[j]++;
        if (key[j] != 0) break;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I used input (not encrypted) data as an index of an array (scrambler connection). The output (encrypted data) is a content of an array (scrambler).

The problem is that when you queue a bit more scramblers in a row (e.g. 100,000) it's being very very slow. So I thought there must be a way to optimize this part (maybe somehow through pointers or linked array?).

This code is currently written in C# and I know that for the best optimization it should be rewritten into C and C++ but let's just leave it like that right now.

**My question is: How can I optimize the code shown above for its purpose (if even possible)?**

Comment: What actually is your question?

Comment: 1. You do not need to "emulate an electric signal", it is just logic. 2. Why would one want to queue 10,000 scramblers in a row? 3. If you are trying to invent your own encryption don't: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): "*Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.*"

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark My question is how can i optimize the code shown above, because now it is inefficient. Maybe somenone already made some form of Enigma emulator, co he/she knows how to tackle this problem.

Comment: @zaph 1. I'm not trying to invent my own encryption. I'm trying to program an Enigma emulator capable of file encryption. 2. It doesn't have to be 10,000 scramblers, it can be 100. My problem is that my code is inefficient.

Comment: "*I'm not trying to invent my own encryption*" immediately followed by "*I'm trying to program an Enigma emulator capable of file encryption*".  Please don't use this for anything important :)

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark OK, so are you able to tell if my implementation of Enigma (the code above) is incorrect? Btw, of course I'm not gonna use an encryption method from WW2 for anything important.